# Angular error cannot find bootstap or theming scss files

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am trying to promote my Angular application to Azure Web App. I updated my project to 15.1.3. When I run ng serve, I receive the error below:

---

./src/styles.scss - Error: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js):
SassError: Can't find stylesheet to import.
╷
6775 │ @import '~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap';
│         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
╵
src\styles.scss 6775:9  root stylesheet

./src/styles.scss?ngGlobalStyle - Error: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/mini-css-extract-plugin/dist/loader.js):
HookWebpackError: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js):
SassError: Can't find stylesheet to import.
╷
61 │ @import '~@angular/material/theming';
│         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
╵
src\styles.scss 61:9  root stylesheet

---

I looked in the node_modules@angular\material and I see the theming.scss file. How do I resolve this issue?

Below is my angular.json file

```
    "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
    "cli": {
        "analytics": false
    },
    "version": 1,
    "newProjectRoot": "projects",
    "projects": {
        "ribo-ng": {
            "projectType": "application",
            "schematics": {
                "@schematics/angular:component": {
                    "style": "scss"
                }
            },
            "root": "",
            "sourceRoot": "src",
            "prefix": "app",
            "architect": {
                "build": {                    
                    "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
                    "options": {
                        "stylePreprocessorOptions": { "includePaths": [ "node_modules/@angular" ] },
                        "allowedCommonJsDependencies": [ "clone-deep" ],
                        "outputPath": "dist/taims",
                        "index": "src/index.html",
                        "main": "src/main.ts",
                        "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
                        "tsConfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
                        "assets": [ "src/favicon.ico", "src/assets" ],
                        "styles": [
                            //"./node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css",
                            "node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.scss",
                            "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
                            "node_modules/owl.carousel/dist/assets/owl.carousel.min.css",
                            "node_modules/owl.carousel/dist/assets/owl.theme.default.min.css",
                            "src/assets/css/animate.min.css",
                            "src/assets/css/boxicons.min.css",
                            "node_modules/magnific-popup/dist/magnific-popup.css",
                            "src/assets/css/flaticon.css",
                            "src/assets/css/meanmenu.css",
                            "src/styles.scss",
                            "src/responsive.scss",
                            "node_modules/ngx-bootstrap/datepicker/bs-datepicker.css",
                            "node_modules/@ng-select/ng-select/themes/default.theme.css"
                        ],
                        "scripts": [
                            "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
                            "node_modules/popper.js/dist/umd/popper.min.js",
                            "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js",
                            "node_modules/owl.carousel/dist/owl.carousel.min.js",
                            "node_modules/magnific-popup/dist/jquery.magnific-popup.min.js",
                            "src/assets/js/meanmenu.js",
                            "node_modules/wowjs/dist/wow.js",
                            "src/assets/js/custom.js"
                        ],
                        "vendorChunk": true,
                        "extractLicenses": false,
                        "buildOptimizer": false,
                        "sourceMap": true,
                        "optimization": false,
                        "namedChunks": true
                    },
                    "configurations": {
                        "production": {
                            "fileReplacements": [
                                {
                                    "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                                    "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                                }
                            ],
                            "optimization": true,
                            "outputHashing": "all",
                            "sourceMap": false,
                            "namedChunks": false,
                            "extractLicenses": true,
                            "vendorChunk": false,
                            "buildOptimizer": true,
                            "budgets": [
                                {
                                    "type": "initial",
                                    "maximumWarning": "80mb",
                                    "maximumError": "100mb"
                                },
                                {
                                    "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                                    "maximumWarning": "200kb",
                                    "maximumError": "200kb"
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    },
                    "defaultConfiguration": ""
                },
                "serve": {
                    "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
                    "options": {
                        "browserTarget": "ribo-ng:build"
                    },
                    "configurations": {
                        "production": {
                            "browserTarget": "ribo-ng:build:production"
                        }
                    }
                },
                "extract-i18n": {
                    "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
                    "options": {
                        "browserTarget": "ribo-ng:build"
                    }
                },
                "test": {
                    "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
                    "options": {
                        "main": "src/test.ts",
                        "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
                        "tsConfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
                        "karmaConfig": "karma.conf.js",
                        "assets": ["src/favicon.ico", "src/assets"],
                        "styles": [
                            //"./node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css",
                            "src/styles.scss"
                        ],
                        "scripts": []
                    }
                },
                "e2e": {
                    "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:protractor",
                    "options": {
                        "protractorConfig": "e2e/protractor.conf.js",
                        "devServerTarget": "ribo-ng:serve"
                    },
                    "configurations": {
                        "production": {
                            "devServerTarget": "ribo-ng:serve:production"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```